# Customizing the webix header

Tags: javascript, jquery, webix

Is it possible to customize the webix UI header like the one in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9Im.png). I want to give an image, a title, a welcome user line with a logout button, and a menu bar to navigate to other pages? Please click on 1 you will get the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that with a toolbar widget :

```
{
  view:'toolbar', 

  css:'header', 
  elements: [
    { view: "label", label: "", width: 100, height: 38, css:'app-logo' },
    { view: "label", label: "My app" },
    {},
    {
      view: "button",
      type: "icon",
      id: 'app:toolbar:current_user_menu',
      icon: 'user',
      borderless: true,
      autowidth: true,
      label: 'Jean bombeur'
    }
   ]

}
```

Then customize app-logo css class to have a background image of your logo.

See demo snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/4f6131d3

Answer (score 0):

You can format the header by providing your own html like below eg:

`{id:"col1", header:"<input type='button' value='Do something' class='dummy_button'>"}`

By adding styles (css), you can design it as per your requirement.